# Adding New Form to Project - Windows Form Application C# (using Macbook)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, windows-forms-designer

Background of what I already have: I have a project named RunTotal. Inside the project I have 1 form called Form1 which contains textboxes, labels and 1 button.

What I'm trying to do: When the user clicks the button inside Form1 I want this new form to open.

I have my MacBook partitioned so I can run both Windows and MacOS. I'm not sure if the partition makes it different in Visual Studio but I'm having trouble adding another Windows Form Application to my project.

So my questions are:

- Do I need a specific type of form because I saw something about inheritance when researching. Since I'm trying to open this new form when a button is clicked on the form I already have, do I need a specific type?
- How do you add a new form because when I try to add a new file, I don't see new Windows Form Application anywhere?

*I don't have 10 reputation yet so I can't post an image of what I get but when I try to go to File -> New -> New File I only see Tex File, HTML Page etc.

Thanks!

Comment: If you right-click on your project from the solution explorer and go to Add --> New Item do you in the Windows Forms category from the left, there should be a "Form (Windows Forms) option in the list, do you see this?

Comment: I see only Installed and then under it I see General, Performance, and Test Settings. The under installed I see Online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add a new Windows Form Application for add a new form to your application. Your application have as default form Form1 usually.

[image]

Than you just right click on the project

Add--> New Item  and a new window will appear

[image]

Select new Windows Form and press Add

After that you will have both forms on the solution

[image]

In the Form1 set the event for the button something similar to this

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var form2 = new Form2();
        form2.Show();

    }
```

use `form2.Show()` if you want to interact with both forms otherwise use  `form2.ShowDialog()`  for block the calling form until the called is closed

Comment: I don't see Visual C# Items like how you have it in your image.

Comment: have you started a new project? File-->New-->Project-->Windows forms app ?

Comment: I think I'm getting confused. So you're saying that if I have my project open right now and want to add another form in the SAME project then I do File-->New-->Project-->Windows forms app? Because I'm opening the project and then right clicking on and going to Add -> New Item. I'm getting confused because I just want another form in the project but the path you wrote has Project in it so I thought that creates a whole new project, which I don't want. @StefanoCavion

Comment: @charmypatel what i'm saying is: after you start/open a project for add a new form you have to follow the steps in the answer, but for having the C# items like in my images you have litteraly just create a project, selecting Visual C# as language to use, nothing more. If you don't have it , maybe you have created a wrong project.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to add

> Windows Form Application

but

> Windows Form

by rigth clik on your project or any subfolder and select ***Add***.

(If it is not listed for some reason, go for ***New item***. Then select ***Windows Form*** under ***Windows Forms*** in ***Visual c#*** category.)

In the click event of your button, use:

```
var f2 = new Form2();
f2.Show();
```

or

```
using (var f2 = new Form2())
{
    f2.ShowDialog();
}
```